# Mass-remove Bezier Curves in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, bezier-curve

Is there a way in Adobe Illustrator to delete all the Bezier curve handles at once from a path?

I created a pattern brush which consists just of a geometric path (without any bezier curve, just straight lines). After I used that pattern brush on a circle, Illustrator created bezier curves to fit the pattern around the circle. I would like to get rid just of the bezier handles all at once, so it leaves me with the path around the circle with just straight lines again.

I can and will of course do it by hand, but I wonder if there is a way to automate that "clean up" process and get rid of all of them at once?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Select all points with the **Direct Selection Tool**, the white pointer

[image]

- Menu Object > Path > Simplify

[image]

To remove handles:

- Select the half of the points making a frame with the **Direct Selection Tool**
- On the top options, click first the **Convert selected anchor points to smooth** button, the green arrow on the image.
- On the top options, click the **Convert selected anchor points to corner** button, the red arrow on the image.

[image]

- Do the same with the other half

Comment: This works if the brush didnt add more points which it tends to do!

Comment: @joojaa You are right, i fixed the answer

Comment: if yoi check straight lines it fixes all if you raise the ange a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Not asked, but obviously you need a big star with quite small radius difference. Use the star tool for it.

[image]

Comment: Yeah but it seems to me that this is probably just a proxy for what OP wants to do ;)

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a brush here.

- Draw a circle
- Choose `Effect > Distort & Transform > Zig Zag` and adjust settings to your liking
  [image]
  Under the "Points" area, be certain `Corner` is selected. Then click `OKAY`.
- If you then need access to the anchors for the zig zag, choose `Object > Expand Appearance` otherwise you can go back and edit the zig zag whenever needed by clicking the item in the **Appearance Panel**.

You are left with the zig zag and corner anchor points, no curves.

[image]

[image]